# Arrest records. Case never filed

Tags: criminal-law

If I got arrested 2 years ago but the case was never picked up and never got the chance to see the judge because the state didnt press charges and the person never pressed charges will it still show up on my background?  I went to the. Courthouse to get a background check and they said I have nothing and if I was arrested 2 yrs ago it was never filed. What does that mean?

Comment: related: [If someone's record has been expunged, can they legally say that they have not been arrested?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/3572/3754)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a record of your arrest which would show up in a background search (although the jurisdiction in question, i.e. the country, or sub-division of a country such as a U.S. state in countries organized on a federal basis, would matter).

Generally, a failure to seek criminal charges does not mean that there is no record of your arrest.

The courthouse is often not the bureaucratic entity that maintains arrest records. In many jurisdictions, arrest records (unlike records of criminal charges and criminal convictions) are maintained by law enforcement rather than the courts.

Whether it is possible to have arrest records sealed is a separate and more complicated and jurisdiction specific question.